# How to fix ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.x port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: server, ssh, multipass

I am new to running ubuntu so not sure what I am missing here

**on My Old macbook pro (ubuntu server running):**
-I installed ubuntu multipass
-created an ubuntu instance
-with multipass list command I can see it running

**on my new Macbook Pro:**
-I created the ssh key, copied the public

**on My Old macbook pro (ubuntu server running):**

- I appended the ssh using nano in the authorized_keys and sure its saved

**on my new Macbook Pro:**

- running command ssh ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx (with correct ip address of course)

it hangs for about a minute then spits out the following
How to fix ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.x port 22: Operation timed out

I tried running
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ssh
sudo ufw allow 22

and completely turned of the firewall on the old Macbook pro but nothing worked

any ideas why I cant seem to be able to ssh into it remotely? I also made sure its the only server running. But nothing seems to work

I can run multipass shell of course. since I added the keys.

THanks in advance

Comment: You say you're using the correct IP address, but that's a classic error message that occurs when folks are not using the correct IP address. Ensure the client and server are on the same subnet. Test the connection using ping.

Comment: Raed- Since you didn't mention adding a network interface set to bridge I'll assume you didn't and need to. Follow the link and scroll to "Bridging": https://multipass.run/docs/using-virtualbox-in-multipass-macos BTW: I will also assume you are wise and created the VM on your old, presumably Intel-based MacBook running VirtualBox knowing the required VirtualBox driver required for the fix doesn't run on your Apple Silicon based MacBook --assuming it is :)